# Copy char array into QByte Array without just passing the pointer

Tags: c++, qt

I want to copy a char array to a QByteArray.

The Function :

```
char *tmpData = new char[64];
.....
msg->mBuffer = QByteArray::fromRawData(tmpData,msg->mBufferLen);
....
delete[] tmpData;
```

is just passing the pointer:

> From Documentation: Constructs a QByteArray that uses the first size bytes of the data array. The bytes are not copied. The QByteArray will contain the data pointer.

After I delete the tmpData, the values which QByteArray is pointing of are gone.
How can I make a copy with qt tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`QByteArray::QByteArray(const char*, int)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#QByteArray-1) constructor documentation, we can see that

> QByteArray makes a deep copy of the string data.

as opposed to the static [`QByteArray::fromRawData`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromRawData), for which the following semantics are stated:

> Constructs a QByteArray that uses the first size bytes of the data array. The bytes are not copied.

Hence, you should be able to obtain a deep copy of the data by

```
msg->mBuffer = QByteArray(tmpData, msg->mBufferLen);
```

and deallocating `tmpData` after construction of `msg->mBuffer` should be fine.

Comment: that's it! somtimes ist's so easy I can't see it :D

Comment: @Hoehli Welcome to stackoverflow, if you find an answer that solves your problem, an upvote to the answer shows your gratitude to the person

Comment: @Gurushant Thanks ;)

Comment: @lubgr You're Welcome :)

Comment: Upvotes from persons with less them 15points of reputation are recorded, but not displayed...

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [appropriate constructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#QByteArray-1) to make a deep copy of the data...

```
char *tmpData = new char[64];
.....
msg->mBuffer = QByteArray(tmpData, msg->mBufferLen);
....
delete[] tmpData;
```

As an aside, you should consider using a container such as `std::vector` rather than having explicit `new`/`delete` calls in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using the naked array to begin with. Transform your code to:

```
{
  QByteArray tmpData(64, Qt::Uninitialized);
  .....
  msg->mBuffer = tmpData;
  .....
} // tmpData gets automatically destructed here
```

You can use `tmpData` in most contexts where `char *` is expected.